# Titanium Facebook module issue

Tags: ios, facebook, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using the native Facebook Titanium module and I have the following issue.

In my app, you can login to FB from two different windows.

In the first one, I instatiated the module and added to the module a 'login' listener.

In the second window I did the same, I instantiated the module and added a 'login' listener.

Problem is the following: the second addEventListener doesn't overwrite the first (it looks like the second Facebook 'require' is simply a pointer to the module instantiated in the first window).

So, it happens the following: when I try to authorize the user and I enter the login listener, it turns out I'm always calling the first one, not the second (the second never gets called).

I tried to remove the first eventListener with no luck. Moreover, they 'live' in distant windows and it seems there's no way to remove this listener correctly.

Any help is appreciated,
Iannis

Comment: Why not put all the logic in a sharedInstance you can access from multiple controllers?

Comment: I don't want to share anything, I want to different objects

Comment: Hi 3000! try add and remove events using https://gist.github.com/minhnc/2333095

Comment: My situation is different: problem is I need to replace an eventListener with another one: this works until the eventListener is in a place other than the root of the app, but if the event is there I can't replace it

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will clarify what you are seeing:

- It's standard CommonJS behaviour that modules are cached and the second and following `require()` will get you a reference to the first instance.
- Like the name says `addEventListener` adds an event listener and does not replace one added earlier.

You should get the `login` event twice, once for each event listener you add. I can't tell why it doesn't do that for you without further insight in your code.

Comment: Hi Fokke (and thanks): I generally use CommonJS modules to create "templates" (I call them "instances") of interactive objects. Now it looks like I'm always modifying the same instance, so that, when I instantiate it (using require) in another window, I'm always pointing to that one, and if I add a listener to that one, the login is shared with another instance in another window. I "solved" by doing a crazy thing: on login I fire a custom event. I can't add another login listener, it doesn't work. I can remove it, then add it again, but then I must add it back to the "first" instance...

Comment: The two instances are in two different windows, one in the root of a navigation controller (iOS), the other one many windows "after" this window. The problem is that, based on the window, the login body must perform different actions: if you are in the first window (for example), it must open another window and make a server call, while the second window must close itself before performing some calculations. SO, if the login is SHARED, the app goes crazy...

Comment: If you cannot add multiple event listeners to the facebook module's login event then that's a bug. Please create a test case (single file reproducing app.js file) and create a JIRA ticket (jira.appcelerator.org) so we can reproduce and fix it.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it as soon as possible (I hope I can do it next saturday morning)

Comment: Any news to this?